# When using xunit.gherkin.quick over SpecFlow, how do you tackle transforms so you can achieve <HasOrHasNot>?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, gherkin

I am trying to replicate a feature currently in SpecFlow called a Step Argument Transformation but using Xunit Gherkin Quick.

Imagine I have a scenario outline, if I have the following given:

```
Scenario Outline: A customer might visit the home page
Given the customer <HasOrHasNot> visited the home page
.....
Examples:
| HasOrHasNot |
| HasNot      |
```

I want to be able to transform that string into a bool so that we can set the context of the testing scenario in a clean way. Is this only a feature in SpecFlow or is Gherkin Quick able to achieve this some way?

Looking at the documentation it doesn't appear possible.

I may need to write some custom code which is called before setting up the context as a workaround.

Comment: Gary, are you trying to say that you want to run the same scenario twice, once passing true into the `<HasOrHasNot>` and then again with false in it? Is that your question? If so, have you tried doing so using Scenario Outlines? They can do this kind of thing: https://github.com/ttutisani/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick/blob/master/docs/scenario-outline.md. Unless you are asking something else, and then please clarify.

Comment: @Tengiz, apologies for not making it clear enough. I have updated the question. This is a scenario outline. The problem is to do with transformation of the "HasNot" into a bool. With [Specflow](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Step-Argument-Conversions) this is done with a step argument transform. I do not know of a way to do this without creating a helper method but that's not as tidy.

Comment: Yes, the question is slightly more clear, although I am not very familiar with Specflow's feature for argument transform. However, why can't you just list the argument values in the examples table? That's what you'd usually do with Scneario Outline, as this page explains: https://github.com/ttutisani/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick/blob/master/docs/scenario-outline.md
It's not quite clear to me why you hesitate to specify the values in the examples table. Is it because the value is not a simple bool? You would use transforms with complex types, but not with bools I guess.